# Reduce supply from 4V to 3.3V

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switching-regulator, 3.3v

**What is the simplest and cheaper way to have 3.3V 0.5A from 4V?**

I'm developing a board which uses a SIM800 so it must have 4V 2A power input from 24V external power supply (I'm using a LM2596S adj, able to supply 4V 3A). SIM800 has 4V Vdd and 3.3V logical input/output.

The rest of the board (microcontroller, etc) needs 3.3V, so I want to take it from the 4V (because if I take it from 24V I would need another step-down converter... and that means more components and cash).

The cheap AMS1117 has 1V dropout voltage, so it's not suitable.
The cheap MCP1700 has only 250mA output current.

*What's about to use diodes to get this voltage?
There is another cheap regulator with less than 0.7V dropout voltage?*

3.3V 500mA is needed (STM32 Cortex M0 + wiznet w5500 + some leds...). Efficiency is not a problem (AC power)

Solution:

I will take diode voltage drop as the simplest solution versus cost.

Comment: A series silicon diode comes to mind (drop of 0.7 V).

Comment: By the way, are you planning to have level shifters on the connections between your 3.3V microcontroller and the 4.0V SIM800?

Comment: Use *two* MCP1700's, one for the Cortex M0 and one for the w5500?

Comment: While not what you asked, I expect you're going to have problems powering the SIM800 in the way you plan.

Comment: Why do you think that @ChrisStratton??

Comment: Because it's notoriously hard to get right.  It can be done, but a DIY LM2596 is probably not going to do it.  These modules are really designed to run on battery as they're just the guts of old "feature phones" with slightly different firmware on them.

Comment: As I have tested with arduino + SIM800L + chinese LM2596 board, it works with TCP and UDP packets (what I need to use). I will check voltage drops on the power supply pin as soon as I get a shunt resistor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A warning about using a diode to get 3.3V: the voltage drop does vary with current and temperature. For example a standard 1n4007 might drop 0.6V at 10mA @ 50C and 1V at 1A @ 0C.

Comment: and what's about Zenner ??

Comment: @FranH Zener regulators don't work well when the load current can vary widely.

Comment: Of course, given that a good proportion of components that are described as requiring 3.3V are happy to run on anything from 3.0V to 3.6V, this is perhaps not as bad as it might appear at first...

Answer (score 0):

The term to look for is **low drop out, or ultra low drop out linear regulator**.
Simple to use, reliable and **i guess** sufficient for your application.
Always refer to graphs/tables provided in the datasheet rather than first page description. Please go through datasheet in detail, and also check thermal dissipation to see whether design need a small heatsink or not.

---

Only based on available inputs here is one example:
**too good but costly:** - [TPS79533DCQR](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps795.pdf)
[image]

**moderate priced** - may not be best candidate: [LP38693MPX-3.3](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp38693-q1.pdf)
[image]

---

My frank suggestions:

There are atleast 100s of options for your application need. You are the right person to decide based on your application

1. Is it battery operated? (consider leakage current or quiescent current)
2. do you have space constraint?
3. type of mounting expected
4. regulation needed
5. noise, ripple expectations
6. price
7. Enable disable function needed?
8. is 500 mA max current or real application current?
9. is 3.3 V mandatory, can the circuits operate at lower voltage for example 3 V?

---

I did a search for the regulator in digikey. Here is the [link](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-linear/699?k=regulator&k=&pkeyword=regulator&FV=fffc00a1%2Cfffc0128%2Cfffc01f9%2Ca4027c%2C204041f%2C204007f%2C204008f%2C20400a1%2C20400aa%2C204003c%2C204005c%2C2040061%2C3fc00b5%2Cii1%7C1065%2C1f140000%2Cffe002bb%2C1bcc0032&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25). you can continue from here. price is in the range 60 cents for one. you can explore from there.

Comment: The answers: No battery operated. Not too much space constraint. Surface mounting. Noise/ripple and voltage needed... enought to work with TTL 3.3V. Price as low as possible.   500mA is max current (250 mA operating current)

Comment: @FranH Then I would suggest to start filtering components as per price and keep an eye on Drop out voltage.. A bit higher quiescent current will be acceptable so that price will not be high because of that